# Square bracketed matrices in Mathematica - precision markers?

Tags: matrix, display

I'm trying to display Matrices with square brackets in Mathematica.

I've found this post from a mailing list in 2009 http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Aug/msg00458.html and it seems to work fine for whole numbers and symbols.

```
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
 TemplateBox[{GridBox[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]}, "Identity", 
  DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{StyleBox["[", 
        SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]], #1, 
       StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]}] &)]]

(* Outputs: *)
Identity[{
  {a, b},
  {c, d}
 }]

(* Which displays correctly as a square matrix. *)
```

But as soon as I try to input floating point numbers, I get floating point precision markers displayed. For example:

```
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
 TemplateBox[{GridBox[{{2.1, 1}, {1, 1.2}}]}, "Identity", 
  DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{StyleBox["[", 
        SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]], #1, 
       StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]}] &)]]

(* Outputs: *)
Identity[{
  {2.1000000000000001`, 1},
  {1, 1.2`}
 }]

(* Which displays correctly as a square matrix. *)
```

I don't see any function in there that would force the numbers to be evaluated into machine precision form. I think using HoldForm or others could solve this issue but I'm not too sure where that can be placed since GridBox needs a list and RowBox needs a box - evaluating them individually displays decimal numbers just fine.

For clarification, I'm looking for something like this:

```
(* In the square bracketed matrix display form of course *)
Identity[{
  {2.1, 1},
  {1, 1.2}
 }]
```

Any help for a beginner? Thank you!

Comment: Obviously I think this has to do with floating point representation inaccuracies in binary forms but I want Mathematica to display those numbers symbolically without evaluating them, if that makes sense.

Comment: And if I use Defer[] in one of the matrix elements, I get an error message saying `An unknown box name (Defer) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.`

Comment: Okay, so using ToBoxes[Defer[2.1]] instead of Defer[2.1] seems to have solved the problem. Now just have to figure out how to eliminate the backtick precision marker...

Comment: What about `makeBrackMat[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
 DisplayForm[RowBox[{"[", GridBox[mat], "]"}]]`?

Comment: Probably better: `makeBrackMat[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
 DisplayForm[
  RowBox[{StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]], GridBox[mat], 
    StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]}]]`.

Comment: @Xavier Ugh, that works perfectly! I should've thought to separate out that bit... Thanks!

Comment: @Xavier Actually, I fixed the problem by elaborating on yours :) Using DisplayForm[] instead of NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[]] removed the backtick and other problems :) It also has the advantage of acting like an actual matrix not just a graphic. Thanks for the hint and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
makeBrackMat[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
     DisplayForm[
         RowBox[{StyleBox["[", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]], 
                 GridBox[mat], 
                 StyleBox["]", SpanMaxSize -> \[Infinity]]}
         ]
     ];
```

Exact numbers:

```
mat1 = Partition[Range[12], 3];
makeBrackMat[mat1]
```

[image]

Machine-precision numbers:

```
mat2 = {{1.3, 2.9}, {9.5, 8.4}, {7.6, 0.2}};
makeBrackMat[mat2]
```

[image]