# How to change the brackets on a matrix

Tags: matrix, formatting

I am trying to write determinates of Matrices in Mathimatica. I am having an issue since I don't know how to change the brackets of an inserted matrix from the standard "()" to "||". Furthermore (but less crucial), if it is possible to change them from "()" to "[]" that would also be helpful. Last thing how would I create an augmented matrix in Mathematica?

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: And by "writing" you mean manually typing, yes?

Comment: For formatting det, look up `BracketingBar[]` perhaps, or `\[LeftBracketingBar]`.

Comment: See also the menu Palettes > Writing Assistant.  It has buttons for creating the forms you seek.

Comment: The first question seems essentially a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113828, and the second a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189.

Answer (score 5):

Borrowing from another answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113828), you can make your matrices display with bars using this function:

```
makeBrackMat[mat_?MatrixQ] := DisplayForm[RowBox[{
                                StyleBox["|",SpanMaxSize->\[Infinity]],
                                GridBox[mat],
                                StyleBox["|",SpanMaxSize->\[Infinity]]}]];

makeBrackMat[{{1, 3, 2}, {2, 0, 1}, {5, 2, 2}}]
```

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{|ccccc|}
 &1 & 3 & 2& \\
 &2 & 0 & 1& \\
 &5 & 2 & 2& \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

To create an [augmented matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AugmentedMatrix.html):

```
Module[{A, B, ans},
 A = {{1, 3, 2}, {2, 0, 1}, {5, 2, 2}};
 B = {{4}, {3}, {1}};
 ans = MapThread[Append, {A, B}];
 Flatten /@ ans // MatrixForm]
```

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
 5 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

To display your matrix with bars, you could use:

```
Grid[{{1, 3, 2}, {2, 0, 1}, {5, 2, 2}}, Dividers -> {True, False}]
```

This would give you:

[image: Matrix with bars]